# Spread variable parameter count on generic function

Tags: swift

In javascript it is pretty easy to take a variable count of arguments and pass it to a sub function without the need to modify the sub function. For example, you want to write a wrapper function which takes a generic function as first argument and calls it with the rest of the arguments:

```js
function wrapper(func, ...args) {
    return func(...args)
}
```

I want to archive something similar in swift. There I have many many c function which I want to wrap with another function for some safety reasons.

Now I have two major road blockers:

The first one: I don't know how to do something like `func(...args)` in swift. This is why I temporary tried this:

```swift
    private func apply<ReturnValue, FunctionParams>(_ fun: (_ params: FunctionParams...) -> ReturnValue, _ paramsPass: [FunctionParams]) throws -> ReturnValue {
        switch paramsPass.count {
        case 0:
            return fun()
        case 1:
            return fun(paramsPass[0])
        case 2:
            return fun(paramsPass[0], paramsPass[1])
        case 3:
            return fun(paramsPass[0], paramsPass[1], paramsPass[2])
        case 4:
            return fun(paramsPass[0], paramsPass[1], paramsPass[2], paramsPass[3])
        case 5:
            return fun(paramsPass[0], paramsPass[1], paramsPass[2], paramsPass[3], paramsPass[4])
        case 6:
            return fun(paramsPass[0], paramsPass[1], paramsPass[2], paramsPass[3], paramsPass[4], paramsPass[5])
        default:
            throw NSError(domain: "apply", code: paramsPass.count, userInfo: nil);
        }
    }
```

This is not really good and only works for a max parameter count of 6.

The second road blocker is, I am not able to write the required swift types to archive something like I described. This is what I tried:

```
    private func runUnsafeFunction<ReturnValue, FunctionParams>(_ fun: (_ params: FunctionParams...) -> ReturnValue, _ paramsPass: FunctionParams...) throws -> ReturnValue {
        // wrapper code
        return try apply(fun, paramsPass)
    }
```

However, if I try to call it, I get: Generic parameter 'ReturnValue' could not be inferred

Probably I miss something here. But at this point I am stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Why not pass the function and its arguments in a closure?

```
func runUnsafeFunction<ReturnValue>(function: () -> ReturnValue) -> ReturnValue {
    // do stuff 
    return function()
}
```

Example

```
func add(_ a: Int, _ b: Int) -> Int {
    a + b
}
func add(_ a: Int, _ b: Int, _ c: Int) -> Int {
    a + b + c
}
let result = runUnsafeFunction { add(3, 4) }
let result2 = runUnsafeFunction { add(3, 4, 5) }
```

Comment: This is my backup plan, but not the ideal solution.